# Exception when mapping json to java object include map

Tags: java, json, jackson

This is my java object want to map json to it:

```
public class ServiceResult {
   private String status;
   private Map<String, MNOFindSubOutPutData> result;
  }

 public class MNOFindSubOutPutData {
     private String status;
     private Subscriber result;
  }
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_DEFAULT)
public class Subscriber implements Serializable {
private String msisdn;  
private Integer latestStatusId; 
}
```

This is my json string:

```
{"status":"success","result":{"123":{"status":"success","result": {"msisdn":"123","latestStatusId":8}}}
```

My code using org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ServiceResult sr=new ServiceResult();
try {
    sr = mapper.readValue(json,sr.getClass());
} catch (JsonParseException e) {
}
```

Then give me when run it this exception:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class com.channelit.advoice.domain.entity.PrivilegeGroup]
```

and I don't know what is the relation of this class(PrivilegeGroup)!!

I am using jackson-all-1.9.0.jar, please help me

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code, unless you have some dependency on PrivilegeGroup class, in one of your value object classes.